# Outlook conflicts with virtual network adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, microsoft-outlook

After installing VirtualBox, a virtual network adapter is added to the system. The problem is that this network adapter is interfering with Outlook in some way. Outlook cannot connect to Microsoft Exchange (the mail server of the organization I work for). Emails are not sent or received.

As soon as I disable the virtual network adapter, the work of Outlook is restored. I tried all the weird tips I could find on the internet (enabling and disabling ipv6, setting metrics, some keys in the registry) - nothing helps.

Can anyone give expert advice on what is the matter here and how to fix it?

(yes, I can manually disable the virtual network adapter each time when I need to receive or send mail, and enable it when I need to work with the virtual machines, but this is inconvenient)

Installed Windows 10 (on Windows 7, there was no such problem)

Comment: Are you able to make a new NAT adapter in VBOX and then delete the first adapter? I am not sure if this will work.

Comment: It does not help.

I have defined the conditions under which Outlook starts working normally:

1.disable virtual network adapter

2.start Outlook (required!)

3.then I can close Outlook, but this is optional

4.enable virtual network adapter.

After that Outlook works until the next system reboot.
if I just disable and enable the adapter (without launching Outlook), then Outlook continues to not see the exchange.

What could it be and how to fix it without restarting the adapter?